# Web aaccess issues. URL just downloads source file rather than displaying in browser

Tags: html, web

I've stumbled across something I have never seen before. I have just set up a new site but whenever I go to any of the URL's on the site browsers just try to download the source file rather than displaying the page.

I have tried this cross browser.

has anyone seen this before?

Thanks in advance,

daniel

Comment: Response headers are incomplete or broken. Show them. You can find them out using Firebug, Chrome dev tools, IE dev tools, Fiddler2, etc.

Comment: my index.php file literally contains the below

<html>
<body>

<h1>header</h1>

<p>Hi</p>

</body>
</html>

just literally trying to display something

Comment: Share the response headers, please. The answer is in there. As to the output, are you seeing PHP code as well? Or is it already parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser download file which not supported by it and this is browser's default behavior

Comment: it is just the index.php file. I dont think that can be the issue

Comment: @Daniel: Even though this answer is terribly written with no respect to the usage of the English language, it has a point. Browsers does not understand PHP. If your webserver is broken in such way that PHP is not executed and the webbrowser thus retrieves the entire raw PHP source code instead of its generated HTML output, then you may experience this behaviour.

Comment: thanks balus ! that was actually the issue. just enabled PHP on the server and its now working fine. sorry for missing something so obvious. the server hosts many of our sites and I assumed (incorrectly) PHP was on as default! thanks to you and also to Sonal